# Stack types for macro

Tags: scala, traits, scala-macros

For a macro implementation I'm stacking types and field names with this boilerplate code:

```scala
trait Init

trait A_ {
  type Push[T]
  val int: Push[Int]    = ???
  val str: Push[String] = ???
}
object A extends A_ {
  type Push[T] = Init with B[Init with T]
}

trait B_ {
  type Push[T]
  val int: Push[Int]    = ???
  val str: Push[String] = ???
}
trait B[Stack] extends B_ {
  type Push[T] = C[Stack with T]
}

trait C[Stack] // etc..

val x: Init with B[Init with Int]   = A.int
val y: C[Init with Int with String] = A.int.str
val z: C[Init with String with Int] = A.str.int
// etc..
```

This works fine. The user can write `A.int.str` or `A.str.int` and the macro can easily extract the involved types and fields.

Since many more types and variations are involved, I'd like to replace `A_` and `B_` with a single base class if possible to avoid the redundancy. So I tried this:

```scala
trait AB {
  type Push[T]
  val int: Push[Int]    = ???
  val str: Push[String] = ???
}
object A extends AB {
  type Push[T] = Init with B[Init with T]
}
trait B[Stack] extends AB {
  type Push[T] = C[Stack with T]
}
trait C[Stack] // etc..

val x: Init with B[Init with Int]    = A.int
val y: Init with B[Init with String] = A.int.str
```

But as you can see, `y` lost the `Int` type on the way.

When calling `str`, the `Push` type used is still the one defined in `A`. I had hoped for the returned `Init with B[Init with T]` to return a new instance of `B[Stack] extends AB` using its `Push` type leading to `C` and so on.

A self reference attempt fails too:

```scala
trait AB { self: {type Push[T]} =>
  val int: Push[Int]    = ???
  val str: Push[String] = ???
}
object A extends AB  {
  type Push[T] = Init with B[Init with T]
}
trait B[Stack] extends AB {
  type Push[T] = C[Stack with T]
}
trait C[Stack] // etc..

val x: A.Push[Int]    = A.int
val y: A.Push[String] = A.int.str
```

I'm obviously missing something and another self reference implementation doesn't work either:

```scala
trait Pusher {
  type Push[T] = _
}
trait AB { self: Pusher =>
  val int: Push[Int]    = ???
  val str: Push[String] = ???
}
object A extends AB with Pusher {
  override type Push[T] = Init with B[Init with T]
}
trait B[Stack] extends AB with Pusher {
  override type Push[T] = C[Stack with T]
}
trait C[Stack] // etc..

val x: A.Push[Int]    = A.int
val y: A.Push[String] = A.int.str
```

Is there a way to have a single implementation of `int`/`str` and get `val y: C[Init with Int with String] = A.int.str` (or something similar) that I can use to extract the types in the macro implementation?

UPDATE:

@AlinGabrielArhip is right in his comment that the type information is actually carried on and compiles even though the types of the second approaches with a single base class are not inferred correctly which show with red lines in IntelliJ.

To give more context to my question, here are the two approaches that you can test in the REPL:

Start scala with `scala -Yrepl-class-based:false´

Paste and run the following 4 sections of code one at a time:

```scala
object SetupA {
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  trait Init

  trait Name {
    val name: String = ""
  }
  trait Age {
    val age: Int = 0
  }

  trait Person0_base {
    type Push[T]
    val name: Push[Name] = ???
    val age : Push[Age]  = ???
  }
  object PersonA extends Person0_base {
    type Push[T] = Init with Person1[Init with T]
  }

  trait Person1_base {
    type Push[T]
    val name: Push[Name] = ???
    val age : Push[Age]  = ???
  }
  trait Person1[Stack] extends Person1_base {
    type Push[T] = Person2[Stack with T]
  }

  trait Person2[Stack]

  def impl[T](c: blackbox.Context)(person: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    q"""
       new Init with Name with Age {
          // Data fetched from db..
          override val name = "Ben"
          override val age  = 42
       }
     """
  }

  def macroA[T](person: Person2[T]): T = macro impl[T]
}
```

```scala
import SetupA._
// Correctly inferred as `Init with Name with Age`
val personA = macroA(PersonA.name.age)
personA.name == "Ben"
personA.age == 42
```

```scala
object SetupB {
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  trait Init

  trait Name {
    val name: String = ""
  }
  trait Age {
    val age: Int = 0
  }

  trait Person_base {
    type Push[T]
    val name: Push[Name] = ???
    val age : Push[Age]  = ???
  }

  object PersonB extends Person_base {
    type Push[T] = Init with Person1[Init with T]
  }
  trait Person1[Stack] extends Person_base {
    type Push[T] = Person2[Stack with T]
  }
  trait Person2[Stack] {
    val get: Stack = ???
  }

  def impl[T](c: blackbox.Context)(person: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    q"""
       new Init with Name with Age {
          // Data fetched from db..
          override val name = "Ben"
          override val age  = 42
       }
     """
  }

  def macroB[T](person: Person2[T]): T = macro impl[T]
}
```

```scala
import SetupB._
// Incorrectly inferred as `PersonB.Push[Age]` - but still compiles!
val personB = macroB(PersonB.name.age)
personB.name == "Ben"
personB.age == 42
```

Is there a workaround to get correct type inference in this case?

Comment: I'm confused by the syntax, what, logically, does something like `A.int.str` or `A.str.int` mean?

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer: It's the builder pattern of putting together a data structure, like for a database call for instance. So, after defining your own schema, you can write for instance `Person.name.age.get` to get that information from the database as typed tuples of `(String, Int)`. See https://www.scalamolecule.org

Comment: Wow, that's a new one for me, ty vm for the clarification. I very much dislike this syntax (beside the point), but I suppose it is quite concise for extraction of a subset of data from a more robust dataset.

Comment: No, `y` has not lost the `Int` along the way, in fact, the line: `val y: Init with B[Init with String] = A.int.str` does not type-check. It throws you a type-mismatch. You've just  found a corner case where the type inferencer breaks and infers the wrong type, but your type is still `val y: C[Init with Int with String] = A.int.str`.

Comment: I'm curious how do you run the code. `Int` and `String` can't be mixed in because they are classes and can't be extended because they are final. The reason the compiler gives you a pass is because you are using them in generics, so the compiler does not even bothers type checking them, they just get erased and replaced with their bounds or `Object` if unbounded, at compile-time. Using `???` gives you another pass, since you can't actually instantiate `int` or `str` in `object A`. Abstract members are intended to be implemented in subclasses, but objects cannot be extended.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip Holy cow, you're right! I guess I haven't wandered wrongly-inferred type land enough :-) Hope that the update explains better what I want to achieve. Do you by chance have an idea how I could get it to infer correctly? Optimally, IntelliJ would just infer it correctly. Will file a bug report.

Comment: Adding some generics and/or bounds instead of abstract types might work. There appear to be some bugs in the type inferencer of the Intellij's Scala plugin. For example, having a method that accepts a `Serializable` parameter and receives an instance of a case class will make the inferencer flag it as a type-mismatch, but the code actually is type-correct, since case classes extend `Serializable`. Glad you sort it out.

Comment: `trait AB {
      type Push[T]
      val int: Push[Int]
      val str: Push[String]
    }

    object A extends AB {
      type Push[T] = Init with B[Init with T]
      override val int: Init with B[Init with Int] = ???
      override val str: Init with B[Init with String] = ???
 }`
Also makes the type inferencer to infer the correct type, in case your were still thinking about a fix for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AlinGabrielArhip! Turned out I couldn't use my simple solution anyway (at least not to my knowledge). As you see in my explanation below I also filed a bug report to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Had made this more complicated than necessary. By simply supplying `Stack` and `Push` as type parameters to the base class, type inference works as expected:

```scala
object Test {
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  trait Init

  trait Name {
    val name: String = ""
  }
  trait Age {
    val age: Int = 0
  }

  trait PersonBase[Stack, Push[_]] {
    val name: Push[Stack with Name] = ???
    val age : Push[Stack with Age]  = ???
  }

  object Person extends PersonBase[Init, Person1]
  trait Person1[Stack] extends PersonBase[Stack, Person2]
  trait Person2[Stack] extends PersonBase[Stack, Person3]
  trait Person3[Stack]

  def impl[T](c: blackbox.Context)(person: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    q"""
       new Init with Name with Age {
          // Data fetched from db...
          override val name = "Ben"
          override val age  = 42
       }
     """
  }
  def m[T](person: Person2[T]): T = macro impl[T]
}
```

```scala
import Test._
val person = m(Person.name.age)
person.name == "Ben"
person.age == 42
```

UPDATE:

Although this answer solves stacking types, it actually doesn't solve the broader problem that the initial use of abstract types was intended for. So I marked it as unanswered.

The problem behind is that the sub classes have varying type parameter arities. So they can't simply be passed as type parameters to a single base class (at least I haven't found a way to do that).

As @AlinGabrielArhip helped me find out, it's a type inference problem and I have submitted [this bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-20413/Nested-abstract-types-incorrectly-inferred) to IntelliJ.

So with a little better understanding of the problem, here's an example of what I want to get working which seems dependent on IntelliJ to fix the type inference bug:

`scala -Yrepl-class-based:false`

```scala
object Setup {

  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  trait Name {
    val name: String = ""
  }
  trait Age {
    val age: Int = -1
  }

  trait PersonAttributes {
    type Next[Attr, Tpe]
    val name: Next[Name, String] = ???
    val age : Next[Age, Int]     = ???
  }

  trait Person0[Obj] extends PersonAttributes {
    type Next[Attr, Tpe] = Person1[Obj with Attr, Tpe]
  }
  trait Person1[Obj, A] extends PersonAttributes {
    type Next[Attr, Tpe] = Person2[Obj with Attr, A, Tpe]
  }
  trait Person2[Obj, A, B] // etc..

  def objImpl[Obj, A, B](c: blackbox.Context)(person2: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    q"""
       new Init with Name with Age {
         // Data fetched from db..
         override val name = "Ben"
         override val age  = 42
       }
     """
  }
  def obj[Obj, A, B](person2: Person2[Obj, A, B]): Obj = macro objImpl[Obj, A, B]
}
```

```scala
import Setup._

trait Init
object Person extends Person0[Init]

// Incorrectly inferred as `PersonB.Push[Age]` - but still compiles!
// Should be inferred as: `Person2[Init with String with Int]`
val person = obj(Person.name.age)
person.name == "Ben"
person.age == 42
```

The initial code example in my question actually only works because `A` defines

```
type Push[T] = Init with B[Init with T]
```

instead of

```
type Push[T] = B[Init with T]
```

The added `Init with` just helped the type inference. But this "trick" doesn't work with the single base class approach.

So now, I simply hope for IntelliJ to fix the bug.